# is it using =integer is faster than =varchar in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

for some reason , I need to use a date range as a "where" condition in my sql.
I need to add a new field data_range in my table , it shoule be varchar or integer, I want to know is it using =integer is faster than =varchar in mysql? and will it be obvious ?

```
select * from table where date_range = '2013-10-01__2013-10-30' use varchar
select * from table where date_range = 2013100120131030 // use integer
```

Comment: If `2013100120131030` is really the size of the number you're using, `int` is too small and you'll need `bigint`; see [`integer types`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) for more info.

Comment: Yuck.  Can't you use pair of date_from / date_to columns, and use the proper data type?

Comment: I got data from google analytics , it only has an date range for to store data into my db, can not use two dates

Comment: Parse the dates out and store in two separate columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary question, "what is faster in a `WHERE` clause, `int` or `varchar`?" isn't what you should be after here.

First, your value is too large to be an `int` and would have to be in a `bigint` field; second, you probably wouldn't want to use `varchar` either but instead favor `char` (since you know the length of your string will be constant). Now, with either of these changes in-place, unless you're performing thousands of queries at a time on hundreds of thousands (or millions) of records - you're not going to notice a performance impact (especially if you index your tables correctly.

Now, the real point. You have two dates and you're merging them into a single column - you shouldn't do this. In a comment, you mentioned that you're receiving the value like this from Google Analytics; however, you should be able to split the value into two separate date values and store them into two separate columns (both a `date` type).

I'm not sure what format you're receiving them in since your question shows them with two separate formats (one with `varchar` that's separated with `__`, the other as an integer with no separator). As you flagged this with PHP, here's how you can split both formats into two separate variables:

A string with delimiters (which also delimit the yyyy-mm-dd, making it quite easy):

```
// assuming a string with a __ delimiter
list($firstDate, $secondDate) = explode('__', $originalDate);
```

A string/integer without delimiters, leaving a format of yyyymmdd:

```
// assuming a string that has no delimiters:
$firstDate = substr($originalDate, 0, 8);
$secondDate = substr($originalDate, 8);
```

A string/integer without delimiters, forcing the yyyy-mm-dd format:

```
// assuming an string that has no delimiters but adding them each in
$firstDate = sprintf("%s-%s-%s", substr($originalDate, 0, 4), substr($originalDate, 4, 2), substr($originalDate, 6, 2));
$secondDate = sprintf("%s-%s-%s", substr($originalDate, 8, 4), substr($originalDate, 12, 2), substr($originalDate, 14, 2));
```

The above three methods can be viewed *in-action* on [**codepad**](http://codepad.org/v3In9Zl9).

If you have the two dates in two separate variables, you can then store them in your database in two separate columns. If your database queries will *always* query with both a "start" and "end" date, you can index both columns into the same index; otherwise, you can index them both separately. Regardless of the use-case, since you will be using them, adding an index will be an important step to assure the speed / optimization you're after =]

Comment: ga's metrics and dimensions can not using date prameter, I can only serach data from start date to end date. http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: @mingfish_004 The `date` parameter is what you're storing in your database; you can format and send it to ga in whatever format they accept. Based on the link you sent me, their format is yyyy-mm-dd, the same format that would be stored in the mysql database - so it should work out well =]

Answer (score -2):

Logically, integer comparisons use fewer bytes and are faster.

That's true, but I've never noticed the difference. This will likely not make a noticeable difference for you, except for the time that it takes you to decide.